# Making a Laser which stops at objects in spritekit

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

Is it possible to make a laserbeam in ios spritekit that will change length depending on the angle and if there is  any objects in the way? its hard to explain but check the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. 'Line Of Sight' type of techniques are very well explained in [Sprite Kit Programming Guide: Simulating Physics chapter.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14)

**Listing 8-10  Casting a ray from the center of the scene** is a code snippet that is on the right track.

Provided the objects that the laser will hit all have physics bodies then you should be able to use `enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart:end:usingBlock:` from **SKPhysicsWorld** class. Think of this method as firing an invisible ray first, so you can get the end point for the laser beam you wish to draw.